# Is there any way to zoom in external display?

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution, settings

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I have two displays. I want to make the display setting "Mirror Display". I can do it by using setting manager or xrandr. But I want my external display mirrored but zoomed in the bottom-left part of the screen.

Is it possible?

Edited: DE is xfce4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could zoom with

```
xrandr --output <Display-Name> --scale 0.5x0.5
#adjust 0.5 (^(-1) = 2x zoom) and <Display-Name>
```

then with arandr move the screens so they overlap to your liking (or do the math by yourself and also do the positioning with xrandr in terminal).

**EDIT:**
Step by step example:
Find the screen name for the screen you want to zoom (this case your external) with xrandr in terminal

```
$ xrandr #will output similar to this
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
[[...] list of modes]
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
[[...] list of modes]
```

this case my active displays are "VGA-0" and "DVI-I-1" (they will differ for your screen), atm DVI-I-1 right to VGA-0. Now we want VGA-0 show zoomed mirror of bottom-left quarter from DVI-I-1. So we execute in terminal:

```
$ xrandr --output VGA-0 --scale 0.5x0.5 #or i.e. 0.75 for 1.333x zoom factor
```

thereafter we start arandr and drag the screens like so:

[image: arandr configuration]

click "apply". See if we got what we wanted, we export via "safe as" to a shellscript containing (in this case):

```
 xrandr --output VGA-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x540 --rotate normal --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
```

we can add the zoom part to this:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --scale 0.5x0.5  --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x540 --rotate normal --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
```

now when we execute this command (in terminal, or via shellscript, ...) VGA-0 will be zoomed and put at pos 0x540 (DVI-I-1 not zoomed at 0x0).

Note that your screen names, resolution, desired zoom-level etc. will/may vary, so you have to adjust to your (and each new) screen.

Also note that some zoom factors will yield blurry results.

Side note: I used this for zooming out, wich made me able to play a game with fixed resolution on my netbook with sightly lower display resolution than desired – just noting, that's also possible ^^

**EDIT2:**
Another way to zoom would be changing the resolution with arandr (right click screen icon to get to context menu -> resolution), and drag screens to overlap like shown above.

pro:

- less likely to blur
- doable with pure gui-workflow

con:

- limited to resolutions the monitor device claims to provide

Comment: @kaj-dj thanks. btw, is there any way to make the display zoomed in to bottom-left?

Comment: i edited the answer to contain the positioning

Comment: @kaj-dj thanks again for the help. I also found another solution `xrandr --output eDP1 --transform 0.25,0,-100,0,0.25,576,0,0,1` but here you need some knowledge about openGL